# Add item to JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I create `JSON` object as:

```
var myJsonObject = JSON.stringify(objectString)
```

How I can add another item into `myJsonObject`??

Comment: are you sure you need `JSON.stringify()`? don't you mean `JSON.parse()`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`myJsonObject` is now a **string** you cannot add anything to it again until you change it *back* into a JSON object.

So you *can* technically do:

```
var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(myJsonObject); //change to obj
myJsonObject.somethingnew = true; //add something
myJsonObject = JSON.stringify(myJsonObject); //change back to string
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you're re-serializing the string rather than parsing it.

```
var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(objectString);
```

then you can add a new item by using

```
myJsonObject['newItemName'] = newValue;
```

Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want to have an array of objects, you can do it like this:

```
//create an array with the result of your object (see the [] characters)
var myJsonArrayObject = JSON.stringify( [ objectString ] );

//add a new element to the array: parse the JSON, push the new element and stringify again:
JSON.stringify( JSON.parse( myJsonArrayObject ).push( newObject ) );
```